# WPF Loading screen for MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am not sure where to begin with this so any help would be great.  My application needs log on/loading screen.  The first window will validate the user against a database then load multiple collections.  Once done loading the "Log on/loading screen" closes and the actual main window appears.  So this is not a true parent child relationship.

The loading of each collection is done ModelView.  This is what I am trying to do, in the "Log on/loading screen";

```
MyViewModel _MyVM = new MyViewModel();
var newWindows = new MainWindow();
newWindows.Show();
this.Close();
```

The problem is figure out how to call the _MyVM in the MainWindow.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could open your LogOn view with the methode ShowDialog before the call to InitializeComponent() on your MainWindow

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking how to give the viewmodel to the window to be its `DataContext`:

```
MyViewModel _MyVM = new MyViewModel();
var newWindows = new MainWindow { DataContext = _MyVM };
newWindows.Show();
this.Close();
```